# How to strip everything but the first 2 characters for each item in a list?

Tags: python

I'm using a list generated from from a directory containing multiple config files. All the config files follow the same naming convention, they start with two letters, followed by 2-3 numbers and end in .conf

```
aa01.conf, aa02.conf, aa03.conf, bb01.conf, bb02.conf,...zz99.conf, zz100.conf
```

I am only interested in the two letters at the start of the each file. How do I strip the numbers, the '.conf', and then remove all duplicates from the result?

Comment: Look at one of these https://stackoverflow.com/q/7961363/1741542, https://stackoverflow.com/q/480214/1741542

Comment: list(set([_[:2].strip() for _ in "aa01.conf, aa02.conf".split()]))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing duplicates in the lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-the-lists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want the first two characters:

```
list_1 = ['aa01.conf', 'aa02.conf', 'aa03.conf', ... 'zz99.conf', 'zz100.conf']
list_2 = [item[:2] for item in list_1]
```

To remove the duplicates

```
list_3 = list(set(list_2))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate you taking the time to answer something so simple :)

Answer (score 0):

to have first two chars and extension, you can do something like this

```
your_list = ["aa01.conf", "aa02.conf", "aa03.conf", "bb01.conf", "bb02.conf"]

your_list_with_out_duplicates = list(set(your_list))
your_lis_of_first_two_char = [
    f"{x[:2]}.{x[-4:]}" for x in your_list_with_out_duplicates
]
print(your_lis_of_first_two_char)
```

**output**

```
['bb.conf', 'aa.conf', 'aa.conf', 'aa.conf', 'bb.conf']
```